# PHP OpenDir function doesnt work on my Ubuntu Linux machine

Tags: php, linux, file, opendir

Recently I changed the OS for my machine from Windows to Linux but now my PHP application doesn't seem to run the `opendir()` function within the new machine. Below is my code:

```
public function scandirs($dir){

    $listDir = array();

    if($handler = @opendir($dir)) {

        while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE) {

            if ($sub != "." && $sub != ".." && $sub != "Thumb.db") {

                if(is_file($dir."/".$sub)) {

                    $listDir[] = $dir.'\\'.$sub;
                }
                elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$sub)){

                    $listDir[$sub] = scandirs($dir."\\".$sub);
                }
            }
        }   

        closedir($handler);
    }

    return $listDir;  
}
```

If I perform a `var_dump(opendir($dir));` it just returns a false.

**EDIT**

I need to add that I am running the files from the Linux Terminal.

Comment: What is the content of variable `$dir`?

Comment: the address is /var/www/html/esurance365/app/sys/project

Comment: If you run the script from the command line (Terminal) it is executed with your permissions. What is the output of `ls /var/www/html/esurance365/app/sys/project` in the Terminal? Is `project` a directory? [`opendir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) fails if its first argument is not a directory (or it is not allowed to open it). Remove the [errors suppression operator (`@`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and let it display why it fails.

Comment: @axiac I have removed it and it just returns a bool(false)

Comment: Probably your errors are suppressed at the global level (or logged into `php_errors.log`). Put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` on top of the script and you'll get them on screen.

Answer (score 0):

It can be **directory permission** issue. Check the permission of directory which you are trying to open.
File permission and File path are two common issues we face when we switch our php application from windows to Linux environment.

Comment: The file permissions are for full read, write and execute permissions

Comment: You are executing the script through browser or through cron?

Comment: No through the Linux Terminal

Comment: Does your user from which you have logged-in have all permissions which you mentioned earlier ?